# How can I make an image from the current environment to share docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have some services running when I run `docker-compose up` command. Now I want to make an image from the current environment and share it with `docker hub` so that every time I can use `docker pull/run my_own_image` command from the docker hub.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use [`docker push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) and [`docker login`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) to login into your Hub account.

Comment: @StefanGolubović in the link I found from only one container to an image but I need all running containers to an image

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much anything that you can do with images or containers with Docker, you can do with Compose. In your case, since you can push your custom image to your Docker Hub registry using `docker image push` (or `docker push`) command, you can do the same with Compose.

As for Compose, you use [`docker-compose push`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/) (no surprises there – consistency between APIs/CLIs).

---

**Tip**: when in doubt, use `--help`. It's the best way (next to Google) to explore CLI. If not sure what are available commands/options for Compose, just type `docker-compose --help`. If you want to see available options for `push` command (for example), use `docker-compose push --help`.